# Seeing +/~ votes at 1k reputation

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

So, I got to 1000 reputation, but still can't see the Up/Down vote breakdown... Any ideas why?

Comment: did u refer this : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly it!

Comment: What happens when you do click the number?

Comment: Voila! Idiot me didn't know I had to click the number!

Comment: The help center document *does* say so... ;)

Comment: I obviously have to start RTFM. :D

Comment: @SebastianKessel Congrats on 10k!